# Matlab - two active GUIs

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have one GUI (GUI1) with Button (Btn1). When I click the Btn1 a second window with plot (GUI2) appers and GUI1 becomes inactive (GUI2.fig and GUI.m are saved to disk). How to make both windows active?

I've tride something like this but it did not work:

```
InterfaceObj=findobj(fig,'Enable','on'); % fig = gcf;
set(InterfaceObj,'Enable','on');
```

GUI2 is invoked as follows:

```
h = GUI2;
```

Thanks for the answers!

My code:
    function visual_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) %Btn1
    % hObject    handle to visual (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

```
PDB_=getappdata(gcf,'PDB_');
file_=getappdata(gcf,'file_');
set(handles.PDB_list,'String', PDB_ );
SelectedItem = get(handles.PDB_list,'Value');
setappdata(gcf,'SelectedItem',SelectedItem);

fig = gcf;


h = GUI2; % GUI2.fig and .m file

visual(file_(SelectedItem,:)); %visual() is the function that generates my graph

InterfaceObj=findobj(fig,'Enable','on');
set(InterfaceObj,'Enable','on');


end
```

Comment: What do you mean "active"? This is a limitation of your operating system such that two windows can't be the active window at once.

Comment: When i try to click on GUI1 its blocked. There is some way to bypass this Windows 8 limitation?

Comment: What do you mean that it's "blocked"? Any graphics updates should still occur and you can still click on it to refocus it.

Comment: When i try to click on GUI1 I hear the Windows error sound and GUI1 does not come to the "First plan" (GUI2 is still on top) and I can not operate on GUI1.

Comment: it is not the limitation from your windows, your code opens a gui from another gui and waits for response from that gui so the first gui will be blocked.

Comment: @darenshan You can *definitely* run multiple GUIs at once. You just have to write them correctly. We need to see the actual code to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: How to run multiple GUIs at once?

Comment: @Suever is right , so please insert your code in your post and we try to find why it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

I've done it!
I put the:

```
h = GUI2;
```

Inside the function:

```
mainWindow_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
...
guidata(hObject, handles);
h = GUI2;
end
```

This initialized GUI2 with GUI1 startup.
Thank You very much!